# newline character indenting? (Java)

Tags: java, string, newline, indentation

I am trying to use \n to create a list of strings but whenever I add more than one string, the string indents up to the point of the previous string so an example output would be:

```
0 hello nain
            1 test nain
                       2 huh nain
```

I don't know why its doing this. Here's the code where I create the string:

```
            String[] posts = currentTopic.getMessages("main");
            //String[] postsOutput = new String[posts.length];
            String postsOutput = "0 " + posts[0];

            for(int i = 1; i < posts.length; i++){
                postsOutput += "\n" + i + " " + posts[i];
                //postsOutput[i] = i + posts[i];
            }

            sc.close();
            return postsOutput;
```

I also tried moving the \n to the end of the appending but the result is still the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of newline char.

Comment: By the way, do not append String with '+' operator. Use a StringBuffer or a StringBuilder, especially when in loops... Your code will generate lots of useless objects (instances of String)

Comment: Do not use StringBuffer, it is not synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try \r\n, i.e. carriage return and newline.

Answer (score 6):

that looks like you're on a system where "\n" just gets down (line feed) and you're missing the required carriage return.

That shouldn't be something you should care yourself:  `line.separator` property is adjusting to the host operating system so that it behaves like `System.out.println`.

Comment: +1. @nain33 can use `\r\n`. CR + LF. Chars 13 and 10 respectively on ASCII.

Comment: there should be some Java OS-agnostic variable that can accommodate to that, isn't it ?

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: @Alex: yep, just figured out ^_^

Comment: You can also try `BufferedWriter`. It has a `newLine` method. Anyway it uses `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as @Alex noted :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good example to use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) because `%n` always uses the system specific line seperator. Inside your loop write:

```
postsOutput += String.format("%n%d %d", i, posts[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the property `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, that holds the underlying system newline character.

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String[] posts = currentTopic.getMessages("main");
//String[] postsOutput = new String[posts.length];
String postsOutput = "0 " + posts[0];

for(int i = 1; i < posts.length; i++){
    postsOutput += newline  + i + " " + posts[i];
    //postsOutput[i] = i + posts[i];
}

sc.close();
return postsOutput;
```